# I am getting an unusual behavior with a Google script that calculates a time difference

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following is my spreadsheet:

[image]

This is my spreadsheet script:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  //Retrieving the Timesheet Table sheet for reading and writing
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('15U8dQIPeYkIiA6B4iHXRe3gEoGGRHy25Qv06jHAJ43_QA');
  var Timesheet_Table = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Timesheet Table'));

  //Extract response dataSets from the current form submission
  var timeStamp = e.values[0];
  var formID = e.values[1];
  var inOutChoiceResponse = e.values[2];

  var tsParse = timeStamp.split(" ");
  var tsDate = tsParse[0];
  var tsTime = tsParse[1];


  var lastRow = Timesheet_Table.getLastRow();


  if (inOutChoiceResponse == "Check in") {

    Timesheet_Table.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(ID);
    Timesheet_Table.getRange(lastRow, 2).setValue(timeStamp);
    Timesheet_Table.getRange(lastRow, 3).clearContent();

  } else if (inOutChoiceResponse == "Check out") {

    Timesheet_Table.deleteRow(lastRow);

    var dataRange = Timesheet_Table.getDataRange();
    var dataSet = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i = 1; i < dataSet.length; i++) {

      var volunteerID = dataSet[i][0];
      var sheetDate = dataSet[i][1].getMonth() + 1 + "/" + dataSet[i][1].getDate() + "/" + dataSet[i][1].getFullYear();

      if (volunteerID == formID && sheetDate == tsDate) {

        var rowToEdit = i + 1;
        Timesheet_Table.getRange(rowToEdit, 3).setValue(timeStamp);
        var diff = ((dataSet[i][2] - dataSet[i][1]) / (60 * 1000)) / 60;
        var hoursWorked = precise_round(diff, 2);
        Timesheet_Table.getRange(rowToEdit, 4).setValue(hoursWorked);

        break;
      }
    }
  }
};

function precise_round(num, decimals) {
  var t = Math.pow(10, decimals);
  return (Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals)).toFixed(decimals);
};
```

The problem is that when ever I try to check out a volunteer for the first time through the volunteer check in/out form, it writes -396071.9625 into the Total Hours Worked column.  But, if I check-out the same volunteer a second time, it returns the right positive number value into the Total Hours Worked column.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem must lie here:

```
Timesheet_Table.getRange(rowToEdit, 3).setValue(timeStamp);
var diff = ((dataSet[i][2] - dataSet[i][1]) / (60 * 1000)) / 60;
```

After the value in the sheet is updated, the array dataSet still contains the values from before the update. In this case dataSet[i][2] contains an empty value. You have to make a call to the sheet again, or better, use the value stored in timeStamp in your calculations.